# Assistance in drawing an Obtuse angled triangle $ABC$ with altitudes

Tags: geometry

In obtuse angle $ABC$, with the obtuse angle at $A$, let $D$,$E$,$F$ be the feet of the altitudes through $A$,$B$,$C$. $DE$ is parallel to $CF$, and $DF$ is parallel to the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$.

I am trying to draw the triangle, but I am struggling with perfecting the parallel lines mentioned above.

My try:
[image]

I can't get the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$ to be parallel to $DF$. How can I possibly draw the triangle so that the lines I want are parallel? Is there perhaps a method to drawing triangles with altitudes?

If possible, can someone show me how the correct drawing would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Approximate image using manual tuning

Regarding your question of how the correct drawing would look like:

[image: Construction]

This was created using [Cinderella](http://cinderella.de/) with manual tuning of the configuration till it met the constraints you mentioned.

## Exact coordinates from lengthy computation

You could compute coordinates for the corners, and then think of ways to construct the resulting numbers. Start with $A=(x,y), B=(0,0), C=(1,0)$ and compute everything else from this. Then you have two constraints and two variables, so you can solve that system of equations.

\begin{align*}
A&=(x,y) \\
D&=(x,0) \\
E&=(y^2, (1-x)y)/(x^2 + y^2 - 2x + 1) \\
F&=(x^2, xy)/(x^2+y^2) \\
G&=(x^2+y^2, 0)
\end{align*}

Actually bisecting the angle at $A$ would entail solving a quadratic equation, so I avoided that and instead constructed the point $G$ above by assuming $AG\Vert DF$. Now we have to check two things. The easier one is $DE\Vert CF$. The condition there is

$$y(x - 1)(x^3 + xy^2 - x^2 + y^2)=0\tag1$$

The first two factors are spurious solutions: $y=0$ would be a degenerate triangle, while $x=1$ would have a right angle at $C$ so it couldn't be obtuse. Therefore that last factor describes the solution you are interested in.
Next you have to check $\angle BAG=\angle GAC$. Luckily that comparison can be done without taking square roots. I originally did so using projective geometry, cross ratios and complex numbers, essentially making use of [Laguerre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_formula). But I've got a simpler solution for you, making use of the fact that the dot product is proportional to the cosine of the angle:

\begin{gather*}
\langle B-A,B-A\rangle\cdot\langle G-A,C-A\rangle^2 =
\langle B-A,G-A\rangle^2\cdot\langle C-A,C-A\rangle \\
y^2(x^2 + y^2)(2x^3 + 2xy^2 - 3x^2 - 3y^2 + 1) = 0 \tag2
\end{gather*}

Again the first factors are spurious, denoting a degenerate resp. a complex solution. The solution you want corresponds to the last factor. So now we combine the relevant factors of both $(1)$ and $(2)$ and solve that non-linear system of equations. There are several real solutions:

$$\begin{array}{r|r}
x & y \\\hline
-0.3090169943749474 & -0.4253254041760200 \\
0.8090169943749474 & -0.2628655560595668 \\
1 & 0 \\
0.8090169943749474 & 0.2628655560595668 \\
-0.3090169943749474 & 0.4253254041760200
\end{array}$$

The solution with $y=0$ is obviously degenerate again. The others come in pairs, the sign for the $y$ coordinate swapped, so we can concentrate on the ones with $y>0$. There the solution with $x<0$ will have an obtuse angle at $B$, so the solution we want must be the one with $x>0$ as well, i.e. the fourth row of the table above. The values printed there are approximations of these exact numbers:

$$x=\frac{1+\sqrt5}4\qquad y=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt5}{10}}$$

So you could either use these coordinates to create the drawing in a coordinate-based approach, or you could come up with a construction sequence which constructs these numbers along the corresponding coordinate axes. Not a very elegant approach, but still feasible.

## Towards a better construction

The fact that the above numbers bear a strong relation to the golden ratio might suggest better ways of constructing this triangle, by making use of one of the many possible geometric interpretations of the golden ratio. I wouldn't be at all surprised to find a pentagon lurking somewhere in there. The corner angles are already nice round numbers of $\frac1{10}\pi=18°, \frac3{10}\pi=54°, \frac6{10}\pi=108°$. I verified this using an exact computation. Furthermore, there are a lot of cyclic quadrilaterals, similar triangles and other symmetries which should help with the construction. One way to construct this triangle would start from a regular pentagon, subdivide that twice to obtain a 20-gon then take the $18°$ angle from that as the basis for the construction.

[image: More advanced figure]